# When to have a pathway to ground in op-amp/comparator input?

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, integrated-circuit, comparator, chip-design

When having a comparator IC, when should I put a resistor in series, to ground, or neither?

I have three examples below:

1. I understand **ex1** may be useful to reduce offset voltage due to offset current.
2. I also know that some schematics have resistor to ground like in **ex2**: because very low current goes into op-amp's input, hence one must create a pathway for current to flow to GND.
3. But, according to 2, I should never see direct input into the comparator like in **ex3**. And this comes to the **ex1** as well. But I've seen schematics like this, having no pathway to ground - and I don't know if they're just omitting loads to simplify the diagram or if it's true that sometimes I should not put a pathway to ground. When and why is that the case?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fR5d2x.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I think you've missed the point as to why a path to ground is required. It's not to allow current to flow from your source to ground - there's no requirement for this imposed by the opamp or comparator. The reason you need a current path to ground is to allow the opamp or comparator's own input bias current to flow somewhere. This is the current which *must* flow into or out of the opamp or comparator's inputs in order for it to work correctly.

Answer (score 3):

In ex1, r3 should theoretically be 50Ω to balance R1 and R2 in parallel. But there are very few comparators with enough bias current for a 50Ω unbalance to matter. Look at the input bias current spec for your comparator and quantitatively evaluate the consequences of leaving out R3.

In ex2, as drawn, there is no need for R5, as generator V2 sets the voltage at the input. You need the resistance to ground if the input is a current from a high DC impedance source or if it's capacitively coupled, since then the voltage is indeterminate.

Answer (score 3):

If you add a series resistor, you will limit the max current to the device in the event you go beyond the rails and turn on the protection diodes. Ex1 won't do anything to reduce offset current as almost all opamps/comparators have less than 1uA of input bias current. 1uA through a 100Ω resistor is going to be a very small voltage. As most comparators have voltage offsets in the mV range, 0.1mV or less will be inconsequential.

As for Ext2 since most sources are going to be low impedance and have a source current well above 1uA and don't need a load. All you are doing is loading the source, which unless you need to impedance match in the MHz range, this wouldn't accomplish much.

Answer (score 3):

> When to have a pathway to ground in op-amp/comparator input?

Always, but **none of your circuits miss the input path to ground**. It is provided by the signal source!

The input is connected to ground via the impedance of the input source. If the source has a very high impedance (on the order of 0.1GΩ or more), such as capacitive or piezo sensors, then a large resistor to ground is needed (100kΩ..100MΩ). The resistor will slightly shunt the input signals to ground, so its value has to be adjusted per the characteristics of the signals source. Some sensors have strong output such as piezo accelerometers, and there a 100k resistor may well be high enough unless a very low frequency response is needed.

> I understand ex1 may be useful to reduce offset voltage due to offset current.

Yes. When the resistors are tens to hundreds of *kilo*ohms or more, not hundreds of ohms or less. With the resistors shown, offset currents from any reasonable comparator IC won't cause meaningful input offset.

> I also know that some schematics have resistor to ground like in ex2: because very low current goes into op-amp's input, hence one must create a pathway for current to flow to GND.

The signal source can be usually viewed as a short to ground anyway, except the voltage isn't zero. That resistor is not useful, except when you want to have a *defined output state* from the comparator when the input is unplugged.

> I should never see direct input into the comparator like in ex3

In most cases, that's *exactly* how you'll see it, no resistors.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the amplitude of the generated signal, the length between the generated signal and the comparator and the noise immunity that you want.

imagine that you have a 1v 1khz SIN generator from 1cm to 100cm from the comparator, then you don't care, anything that you put there will be ok, frequency wise and amplitude wise, your signal is strong and the jitter generated will be minimum.

Now, imagine that the signal is not 1v, but 1mv (and you set the threshold for 0.5mV),  then, the noise starts to be important.  if the source its strong (can generate enough current) then adding a paralel resistor (input to ground just beside the input of the comparator) will create a load, this load will allow that any electrostatic noise that you get on your cable will be dumped to ground as electrostatic have week current, meaning that the noise will be kind of shorted to ground.

Now we make it even harder, you have a 10 or 50 m cable... and the voltage is still 1mv.. (we are making it harder here, now is when you need to start thinking a bit more carefully). you need to have a resistor to ground at the input WITH THE SAME IMPEDANCE of the cable and tracks that you are using.  Not fulfilling this requirement will mean that any noise that is capable of getting will go to the comparator, bounce back to source, and bounce back to comparator till the noise is lost through the losses on the cable.

Now let's make it even harder, the signal is 1MHz.. or 100MHz, same as up, you want to have this load, because now even the signal itself is bouncing back and forth. if your cable is 10m, that is 50ns per trip, 100ns.. meaning that without load, your own signal will start reflecting (before it was also reflecting but ms to ns cant be appreciated). now your signal is not sinusoidal any more, it's a distorted signal without a load that allows all the current to go efficiently to ground). in addition, adding a series resistor at the source will allow that any missmatched signal due to connectors impedance or any parasitics that produced a bounce before the comparator will be dumped to this resistor at the source and therefore you will have no double bounces, however you lose some signal amplitude.

The bastards of detector development now they have a new signal... it's a digital signal 500MHz, 1mv over 10m cable... the super fast transitions contain frequencies of up to 5GHz...  same applies but now you need to probably add filters on reception and you may want to consider a different strategy.

In resume, if your signal is strong, then dont worry and be happy
If your signal is weak, the cable is long, use at least a resistor to ground on the comparator, and if you still see noise, then use the source resistor too.

sorry for the over-complicated explanation